# Fast way to sync HDD and Flash Drive?

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, usb-flash-drive

I need to manually sync my HDD to my Flash drive. What I mean by sync is, the HDD must be an exact copy of the Flash drive but not vice versa. Currently every time I need to sync, I simply erase my flash drive the copy my HDD to it.

Is there a faster way to do this? Like is there a program that can check if files already exist in the destination, don't copy it and if a file is gone from the source delete it in the destination. Note though, the whole sync process must be faster than what I'm currently doing.

Comment: I'm a bit confused because you say the HDD must be an exact copy of the flash drive, yet you erase the flash drive beforehand. Regardless, I recommend `rsync` (with Cygwin) for this purpose. If you need a native Windows solution then possibly `robocopy`, although I haven't tried it myself. Both of these are command line utilities. I don't know any GUI utilities to recommend.

Comment: Syncback, you can download the free version. Select mirror. http://www.2brightsparks.com/

Comment: @MikeFitzpatrick The HDD gets deleted/updated with new files once in a while so I need to erase the flash drive to it only copies updated files.

Comment: rsync's --delete option will be helpful then.